# MySQL join on one table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a users-table which is like (shorted):

```
id (BIGINT)
username (VARCHAR)
recommendedByUserId (BIGINT)
```

In `recommendedByUserId` the ID of the recommender is stored, which is the `users.id`-value of the recommender.

Now I need to know how many times each `users.id` is in `users.recommendedByUserId` and sort on them descending, so the user with the most recommendations is on top of the result.

I tried:

```
SELECT u.username, COUNT(r.id) FROM users u INNER JOIN users r ON u.id = r.recommendedByUserId
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `id` is sufficient

```
SELECT recommendedByUserId, COUNT(*) as rec_cnt
FROM users u 
group by recommendedByUserId
order by rec_cnt desc
```

If you also need the name then you can do

```
select u.username, x.rec_cnt 
from users u
inner join
(
    SELECT recommendedByUserId as id, COUNT(*) as rec_cnt 
    FROM users u 
    group by recommendedByUserId
) x on x.id = u.id
order by x.rec_cnt desc
```

Comment: +1, also do the `order by cnt desc` and the answer is complete! :)

Comment: That's great, thank you! I don't understand why my question got a downvote though...

Comment: I have an extended question on the same subject here, any input @juergend? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826457/mysql-count-on-joined-table/18826496

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT recommendedByUserId, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM users us 
group by recommendedByUserId order by cnt desc;
```