# MySQL count on joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a users-table which is like (shorted):

```
id (BIGINT)
username (VARCHAR)
recommendedByUserId (BIGINT)
```

In `recommendedByUserId` the ID of the recommender is stored, which is the `users.id`-value of the recommender. This is working:

```
SELECT u.username, recomm.recommCount, recomm.likesCount
FROM users u
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT recommendedByUserId as rid, COUNT(*) as recommCount, SUM(u.likes) as likesCount
    FROM users u 
    GROUP BY recommendedByUserId
) recomm on recomm.rid = u.id
ORDER BY recomm.recommCount DESC
```

Now I need also to count how many posts a user has which has been recommended by another user and sum that up on the recommender. I thought I could do it like this:

```
SELECT u.username, recomm.recommCount, recomm.likesCount, recomm.postsCount
FROM users u
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT recommendedByUserId as rid, COUNT(*) as recommCount, SUM(u.likes) as likesCount, COUNT(posts.id) AS postsCount
    FROM users u 
    INNER JOIN posts ON u.id = posts.author_id
    GROUP BY recommendedByUserId
) recomm on recomm.rid = u.id

ORDER BY recomm.recommCount DESC
```

but that's giving weird results.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
SELECT u.username, p.postsCount, recomm.recommCount, recomm.likesCount
FROM users u 
JOIN
 (
   SELECT author_id, COUNT(*) AS postsCount
   GROUP BY author_id
 )  AS p
ON u.id = p.author_id
JOIN
 (
   SELECT recommendedByUserId as rid, COUNT(*) as recommCount, SUM(u.likes) as likesCount
   FROM users u 
   GROUP BY recommendedByUserId
 ) recomm ON recomm.rid = u.id
ORDER BY recomm.recommCount DESC
```

Comment: I didn't know if a user might be recommended by multiple users, you're using MySQL and those user sometimes have very strange data models :-)   I modified my answer, should be ok now.

Comment: thank you! I will accept your answer, although I will have to post a new one as some things have changed already :(